# Get Data from Old Realm into New Realm without Migration

Tags: realm, realm-migration

I have an old version of my app (version 4) and I'm building version 5. Version 4 uses Realm and has its own schema. Version 5 has some similarities to version 4, but lots of schema changes.

Migrating all the old data to the new Realm via a schema migration seems a bit overwhelming and maybe even impossible. Let me provide a contrived, simplified example of the sorts of changes I'd have to make.

**Version 4 Schema**

```
class Alpha: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var category = ""
  @objc dynamic var fields = List<Field>()
}
```

**Version 5 Schema**

```
class Alpha: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var category: Category?
}
class Field: Object{
  @objc dynamic var alpha: Alpha?
}
```

As you can see in the example, I need to do things like:

1. Look up the `category` in the new version 5 Realm and associate it with an object instead of it just being a `string`.
2. Stop using `List` on `Alpha` and just point the child object to the parent instead.

It doesn't appear that I can do Realm queries and such while inside a `migrationBlock` so I feel a bit stuck.

Is there a way to open an old Realm and tell it to keep its schema intact (and be read-only), and then parse through its data so I can store it in my new version 5 Realm? Or potentially rename its classes to temporary names so I can access its data without trying to force it into my new schema?

I'd love some ideas on how to handle a situation like this.

---

### Update with More Info

This is a local-only realm. I'm looking to transfer data from the old realm (v4) to the new one (v5).

```
let realmOld = try! Realm(...)
let realmNew = try! Realm(...)

for alpha in realmOld.objects(Alpha.self){
  //--- Move each List object to be a standalone object ---
  for field in alpha.fields{
    let newField = Field()
    newField.name = field.name
    newField.alpha = alpha
  }

  //-- Assign a category object using the category key ---
  let newAlpha = Alpha()
  alpha.category = realmOld.object(ofType: Category.self, forPrimaryKey: alpha.category)
}
```

So this leads to some questions:

1. How can I reference the old schema and the new schema and their respective objects when moving data around?
2. Can a write transaction occur inside a migration block?

Overall I'm just unclear on how to make these transitions with two different Realm schemas.

Comment: For clarity, it appears version 4 had a one-to-many relationship between an Alpha and many Fields. In v5, you have no relationship at all from Alpha to any Fields but a Field knows about a single Alpha. Is that correct? You can certainly open a realm as Read only and 'copy data' from one object to another. You can likely do this within a migration block as well but it's not clear where you want the data to go e.g. `category` was a string and now it's a `Category` object - where should the old string data go. Can you clarify the question? Is this Sync or local only?

Comment: @Jay I added some more context and examples of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I am still not clear what the issue/question is. If you have a `Person` object with say a property `name` and there are number of them stored in Realm. Then, you want to create a new object(s) `Dude` with a `dude_name` property. It looks like you're going the right direction in code but the flow is to read in all of your person objects and iterate over them. Within the iteration create a new dude `let newDude = Dude()` and then 'newDude.dude_name = person.name` and write each one out. That should be straight forward. Perhaps I am not understanding?